# unable to get route name from url in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, routes

I'm using Zend Framework 2, this is my code:

```
$prevsingletrackurl = $this->getRequest()->getHeader('Referer')->getUri();
```

From this code which is defined in a controller's method I'm getting previous URL, now what I need to know some information of this from this, it contains which route, controller, method for my own requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code i have used inside a controller action method

$request = $this->getRequest();
$getHeaderReferer=$request->getHeader('Referer');

```
      if (!empty($getHeaderReferer))
      {


           $prevsingletrackurl = $getHeaderReferer->getUri(); //  get previous url
             //echo "<br>previous usrl=>".$prevsingletrackurl;        
           $controller = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller'); // get controller name




             //**** code to get previous url route , controller name , action/method name starts


               $request->setUri($prevsingletrackurl);
               $router =$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Router');// this gives instance of /Zend/Mv/Router/Http/TreeRouteStack 

               //echo "<br>router=>".$router->toString();
               $routeMatch = $router->match($request); // this gives instance of /Zend/Mv/Router/Http/RouteMatch

               $routename="";




               if( $routeMatch instanceof RouteMatch )
               {

                     $urlwholeroutedataAr=$routeMatch->getParams();

                    if(!empty($urlwholeroutedataAr))
                    {
                         $controllerdata=$urlwholeroutedataAr['controller'];
                         $actionmethod=$urlwholeroutedataAr['action'];

                         if(array_key_exists('trackdata',$urlwholeroutedataAr))
                         {
                            $trackdata=$urlwholeroutedataAr['trackdata'];
                         }

                          $controllerdataAr=explode("\\",$controllerdata);

                          if(count($controllerdataAr)>0)
                          {
                            $controllername=end($controllerdataAr);
                          }



                    }

                     $routename=$routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();
                     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the route stack itself to try to match it. It will return you a RouteMatch if the request object matched:

```php
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch;

$referer = $this->getRequest()->getHeader('Referer')->getUri();
$request = clone $this->getRequest();
$request->setUri($referer);

$match = $routeStack->match($request);
if ($match instanceof RouteMatch) {
    $route = $match->getMatchedRouteName();
}
```

You can access the route stack ("router") from the service locator; in the root service locator, it is registered as 'Router'. You can inject the route stack in your factory. For instance in a Controller:

```php
use MyModule\Controller\MyController;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class MyControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl)
    {
        $router     = $sl->getServiceLocator()->get('Router');
        $controller = new MyController($router);

        return $controller;
    }
}
```

Use it in your controller as this:

```php
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack;

class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(TreeRouteStack $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    protected function getRouter()
    {
        return $this->router;
    }
}
```