# ZF2: How to get the route corresponding to the current url referrer?

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I did not find any answer either from google nor from SO for my question, so I decided to ask.
Is there an easy way to get the params of the route corresponding to the current url's referrer ?

I am in the context of a controller action, so I have access to the **$request** and **$response** objects. I am actually retrieving the referrer using the following:

```
$referer = $request->getHeader('referer');
$refererUri = $referer->getUri();
```

What I do really want is to know if the url I got in the **$refererUri** variable matches a route which has a ***"connect"*** param defined as true, route being defined as the following:

```
'productAdd' => array(
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/product/add',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Module\\Controller\\Product',
                            'action' => 'add',
                            'connect' => true
                        ),
                        'spec' => '/add',
                    ),
                ),
```

Right now I got in my $refererUri variable a URL like

```
http://local.example.com/dir/product/add
```

The solution I already thought about is to instanciate a request object from the URL and then to instanciate a route object from the request object, which will tell me  if it matches. Then if I got a RouteMatch object in return, I will be able to get the value of the param I want.

But it really seems heavy for a pretty quick check, and it seems I cannot achieve that as a Route is not an object I can easily instantiate.

Any ideas ?

Edit: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321123/unable-to-get-route-name-from-url-in-zend-framework-2): which seems pretty close to what I asked for, but in the first answer proposed I cannot get where the **$routeStack** object is coming from. Any clues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally achieved my goal, so I am posting the answer for helping others in the same situation ;-)

What I did is basically :

1. Getting the referer URI:

   ```
   $referer = $request->getHeader('referer');
   $refererUri = $referer->getUri();
   ```
2. Instanciating a request from this URL:

   ```
   $refererRequest = new Request();
   $refererRequest->setUri($refererUri);
   ```
3. Get the router object:

   ```
   $routeStack = $serviceManager->get('Router');
   ```
4. Find which route match the $refererRequest:

   ```
   $match = $routeStack->match($refererRequest);
   ```
5. Check my parameter value from the RouteMatch object I got in return:

   ```
   if ($match instanceof RouteMatch) {
        $route = $match->getMatchedRouteName();
        $connect = $match->getParam('connect');  
   }
   ```

And there it is ;-)